# The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

My C# file shows 3 different errors related to missing assembly references.

I am using Xamarin studio and not sure where the references are located. The assembly browser?

Here is where the errors are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Errors:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (class)
>
> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Specialized' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Collections' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (class)
>
> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (class)

Comment: as the errors suggest, you are missing some assembly references.

Comment: How do I fix this error? @Jodrell

Comment: Go to your references, click on `Add Reference...`. In there find `System.Net`, check its checkbox and click on `OK`.

Comment: add a reference to the project. Choose, "Add Reference" from the "Project" menu if you are using Visual Studio.

Comment: for those 3 errors sounds like a namespace issue can you show the class definition for the 3 ..also if they are 3rd party .dll's you need to add a using reference to the top of the class as well as manually adding the individual references

Comment: Just to be clear, I am using Xamarin studio and not sure where the references are located. The assembly browser?

Comment: `System.Collections.Specialized` and `System.Net` are found in `System.DLL` - no reference should be necessary.

Comment: That is why I am confused to why it is showing any errors @DStanley

Comment: @user3807836 Please add the fact that you are using Xamarin to your question so it gets reopened - that's a critical component of your problem.

Comment: I don't understand, I have already added it? Like much earlier. @DStanley

Comment: @user3807836 The only edit I see is the addition to the question title after I made my comment (and added the tag).  Critical facts made in comments are likely to go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to eliminate the errors by adding references one by one. If the error is thrown try to right click on the References in your project in Solution Explorer and add reference which seems to match to the one which causes error. If this won't help the cause is somewhere else, then post more data about the problem.

Comment: `System.Collections.Specialized` and `System.Net` are found in `System.DLL` - no reference should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still having this problem, but I fixed a similar issue (System.Collections.Specialized does not exist) in Xamarin Studio 6.3 by adding a reference to System through the Edit References dialog.

Answer (score 0):

1_Go to your error giving project.
2_Right click>Add>Reference.
3_Search for 'Net' in Reference Manager window.
4_Find "System.Net" check the box right left to it and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

I use visual studio 2019
when I get this errors,
the fixes is this
1)go to solution explorer. 2) right click on your solution. 3) Add. 4) Reference... 5) In reference manager window search for System.Net 6) check the box. 7) OK

This worked for me.

1
[image: 1]

2
[image: 2]

3
[image: 3]

4
[image: 4]

5
[image: 5]